# Materialize secondary-content wont vertically align properly

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, materialize

I downloaded the materialize SASS folder and JS folder, put it in my file.  Most things are working.

When I try to use the secondary-content in a collection, the button doesnt line up with the description, someone else on here had the same problem, but never got a solution.

Here is my code:

```
<li className="collection-item">
  <div>
    <h5>{email}</h5>
    <button
      className='secondary-content'
      onClick={e => handleClick(e, email, onDelete)}>Delete</button>
  </div>
</li>
```

The button goes below the rest of the

per the image.

[image]

If I use valign-wrapper in the div, it aligns vertically, but loses its float right alignment!

How can I both align vertically and to the right, as I would assume is the expected behavior of secondary-content?

Comment: Just notices, its actually made the last list item with a greater height as well...

Comment: The example from materialize-css docs : <li class="collection-item"><div>Alvin<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">send</i></a></div></li>

Comment: Maybe the problem is because of using `buuton`. you can replace it with `a` tag. If it didn't solve please provide a code-snippet in your question or upload code somewhere like jsfiddle.com, then I'll help you better.